# Connecting bluetooth headphones to a MacBook and phone at the same time?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have Sony WH-1000XM2 headphones which, while being quite old, worked well connected to a Windows laptop and my Android phone at the same time. In Android bluetooth settings, I had Media audio turned off and Phone calls on, which meant media would play from my PC and I could still recieve calls through the headphones. This doesn't seem to be possible with MacOS (Sonoma, M2 MBA). Am I missing something?